# Problems with UIScrollView in landscape mode

Tags: ios, ipad, uikit

I have a problem with my App, any help is greatly appreciated!

Problem description:
When building the App using the code snippets given below, the user can scroll two pages, but only one page shows an image. My expectation is that both pages show an image.

App layout:
The App targets an iPad in **landscape mode** only.

My App uses a UIScrollView to scroll between two different view controllers. Each of the view controllers has an UIImageView embedded in its view. The image of the UIImageView is set via IB. The image has a dimension of 1024x768 pixels.

The view controllers are instantiated in code using the storyboard interface.
The main view controller, which has the UIScrollView embedded in its view, uses the following code to instantiate and add the view controllers containing the image.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Keep the VCs around
    self.viewControllers = [NSMutableArray array];

    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(0, 1024)];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;

    SinglePageViewController *vcOne = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SimpleImageView"];
    [self addViewControllerToScrollView:vcOne];
    [vcOne setViewPositionToHorizontalPage:0];

    SinglePageViewController *vcTwo = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SimpleImageView"];
    [self addViewControllerToScrollView:vcTwo];
    [vcTwo setViewPositionToHorizontalPage:1];
}

- (void)addViewControllerToScrollView:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    CGSize contentSize = self.scrollView.contentSize;
    contentSize.width = contentSize.width + 768;
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:contentSize];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:viewController.view];
    [self.viewControllers addObject:viewController];
}
```

The method setViewPositionToHorizontalPage of the class SinglePageViewController looks like this:

```
- (void)setViewPositionToHorizontalPage:(NSUInteger)pageIndex
{
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(768 * pageIndex, 0, 768, 1024);
}
```

When I use transparent images I can see that both views seem to be positioned at the same position. When I log their frames, they both seem to have the correct values (0,0, 768, 1024) and (768, 0, 768, 1024).

Thanks again for your help!